# Converting an ActiveRecord:Relation to java array

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, activerecord

I am running a 'where' query which is running on a table MyTable in my rails application.
I want to convert the results of a specific column from this query(ActiveRecord::Relation) to Java Array of String type.

This is what I am doing :

```
employeesJavaArray=MyTable.where("salary = ?",100).pluck(:columnName).to_java(java.lang.String)
```

However I am receiving this error in my logs :-

```
TypeError (could not coerce Fixnum to class java.lang.String):
```

Can you please help me out what could be wrong with the statement that I have written.

Comment: What data type does the column `columnName` return?

Comment: I am running the same type of query on multiple tables one of them is returning int and others are returning string.

Comment: I did you try to convert the integers to strings first?

Comment: Nope!,is it because of that?And is there any way to convert an "Array of Integers" to "Array" of Strings" in one line without iterating over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ensure that the array only includes string (by calling `to_s`) first:

```
employeesJavaArray = MyTable.where("salary = ?",100)
                            .pluck(:columnName)
                            .map(&:to_s)
                            .to_java(java.lang.String)
```